# Sonar PreparedStatement - sql injection

Tags: java, prepared-statement, sql-injection, sonarqube

Sonar complains about a method:

> "A prepared statement is generated from a nonconstant String"

I understand, it is not safe to parameterize a query by string concatenation, but here I am defining the name of the table.
How to get rid of the sonar warning? And more importantly, how to fix this issue, how to avoid sql injection?
Should I start searching invalid values in db and node variables, eg. must not contain space or ; (the usual checked input stuff), or is there an elegant way?

Btw, the method is very deep in the app, I doubt there is a chance to force any value upon these parameters by the ui.

The simplified version of the method:

```
private PreparedStatement getPs(Connection conn, String db, String node, String ext) {
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder("select name, sum(counter) cnt");
    sql.append(" from ").append(db).append(".").append(node).append("_stuff");
    sql.append(" where something = ?");
    sql.append(" group by name");

    PreparedStatement ps;
    try {
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
        ps.setString(1, ext);
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        throw new MyRuntimeException(sqle);
    }
    return ps;
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sonar warning tells precisely what it warns about:

> "A prepared statement is generated from a nonconstant String"

That doesn't mean that your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. That simply means that it *could* be. If you're absolutely sure that there is no way for a user to inject a database schema or table name, then simply ignore the warning.